# Assembly Language (68000)- Sorting MOVE instructions according to their speed

Tags: assembly, 68000

Could somone please tell me how to sort this from fastest to slowest? It would be awesome if you could provide an explanation to why you sorted each one in that paticular position.

```
MOVE.W $1234,$8000
MOVE.W #$1234,$4568
MOVE.W D0,D2
MOVE.W D0,$1234
MOVE.W D0,(A0)
```

Comment: What CPU ? 68k family ?

Comment: OK - I've fixed your tags for you now.

Answer (score 2):

The speed depends on how much data there is to read to get the instruction, and how many memory accesses the instruction does:

1: No memory access, no data in instruction:

```
MOVE.W D0,D2
```

2: One memory access, no data in instruction:

```
MOVE.W D0,(A0)
```

3: One memory access, one address in instruction:

```
MOVE.W D0,$1234
```

4: One memory access, one address and one word in instruction:

```
MOVE.W #$1234,$4568
```

5: Two memory accesses, two addresses in instruction:

```
MOVE.W $1234,$8000
```